# How to install SciPy on an Azure C# webapp?

Tags: python, azure, scipy, azure-web-app-service

I have a website built with .Net Core 1.0 (C#) and deployed it to Azure WebApp (32 bit mode).

The app uses some python scripts and I was able to create a virtual env (3.4.1) and successfully installed numpy (1.11.0) with `pip install numpy`.

The problem I'm facing is that I can not install SciPy.  Trying `pip install scipy` fails because of compiler issues which I understand.

Next try was to download Christoph Gohlke's Python Extension Packages for Windows ([from here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy)), copied it to my web app and tried to run 'pip install scipy-0.18.0-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl' without success.  The error I get is:

```
scipy-0.18.0-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
Storing debug log for failure in D:\home\pip\pip.log
```

pip.log contains the following:

```
scipy-0.18.0-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 257, in run
    InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))
  File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 167, in from_line
    raise UnsupportedWheel("%s is not a supported wheel on this platform." % wheel.filename)
pip.exceptions.UnsupportedWheel: scipy-0.18.0-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I have tried to create a requirement.txt file as stated in [Troubleshooting - Package Installation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/#troubleshooting---package-installation).  However since it's not a python app, but instead a dotNet Core C#, it doesn't seem to care about the requirement.txt file and don't see anything about it in the deploy.cmd file.

Comment: Try to first upgrade pip to the latest version `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`, then install numpy+mkl `python -m pip install numpy-1.11.1+mkl-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl`, then install scipy `python -m pip install scipy-0.18.0-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl`. Make sure you have the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) installed.

Comment: @cgohlke that worked as expected.  Not sure how to check if VC++ is installed but the steps worked and I can now use scipy.  If you create an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

@mdeblois, your understanding is correct, please see the offical explaination below.

> Some packages may not install using pip when run on Azure. It may simply be that the package is not available on the Python Package Index. It could be that a compiler is required (a compiler is not available on the machine running the web app in Azure App Service).

For this case, the solution is that you can refer to the section [Troubleshooting - Package Installation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/#troubleshooting---package-installation) of the offical tutorial to know how to deal with.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it more apparent that I did not just try the `pip install scipy` but to also tried to use a windows compiled wheel.  Adding the requirements.txt did not seem to have done anything as it seems that is for python deployments which mine is not.  It just so happens to use some python scripts but it is built using dotnet core with C#.